# "Much feces" vs. "many feces"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number, determiners, collective-nouns

I want to know which word I should use in the following sentence:

> How many/much feces does a human produce in one year?

I found that both versions exist on the Internet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

I would avoid this construction altogether and go for something like

> How **much** *fecal matter* does a human produce in one year?

Indeed, *many feces* is incorrect, as feces are uncountable. *Much feces* is also quite incorrect (and sounds awkward, too), as *feces* is plural by default. Not all uncountable nouns go with *much*. For instance, *scissors* is a **plural uncountable** and both *much scissors* and *many scissors* are incorrect. Instead, one says *many pairs of scissors* to indicate the plural. Thus, you could also introduce a unit of measurement to quantify *feces* in your example:

> How **many** *kiograms/pounds of feces* does a human produce in one year.

Answer (score 6):

*Much.* Feces cannot be counted individually, so it is used with *much*. *Many* is only used with [countable nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_noun).

Comment: As someone who walks a dog, I can unfortunately attest to the fact that fecal matter can be counted. :/

Answer (score 0):

"Much feces" is correct. Even though it ends in *-s*, *feces* is not plural and cannot be counted.

Comment: In Latin, _faeces_ is  the plural of _faex_.

Comment: Pity we're speaking English, then, and not Latin.